# How can i get the extra options on the admin pannel in broadleaf

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I Have Installed Broad leaf Admin and Run Successfully.

But I have only four modules displaying on admin page.

On log in to the Demo at The Broad leaf original site i have seen the extra modules on Admin panel.

How can i get the Remaining options as Displaying on Demo on Broad leaf official site. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly because you are running the community version of Broadleaf Commerce locally. However, the demo version online (where a demo is provisioned for you) includes enterprise features. This explains the difference in the modules you are seeing in the admin when you run locally. If you would like to utilize the enterprise features, you'll need to contact Broadleaf in regard to paying for an enterprise subscription.